# War Card Game C++

Tags: c++, random

I have an assignment that creates the card game War and uses rand_range for the card numbers. If the numbers 11, 12, 13, or 14 pop up I am supposed to change them to J, K, Q, and A, respectively. I cannot figure out how to change the unsigned short for the card numbers to a const char or string.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

unsigned short rand_range(unsigned short min, unsigned short max)
{
    return rand() % (max - min + 1) + min;
}
int main(void)
{srand((unsigned)time(0));
unsigned char suit1 = ' ', suit2 = ' ';                         
unsigned char  verticalLine = ' ', horizontalDouble = ' ';
unsigned char doubleCornerr = ' ', doubleCornerl = ' ', doubleCornerlb = ' ';
unsigned char doubleCornerrb = ' ', topLine = ' ', verticalDouble = ' ', topCornerr = ' ';
unsigned char topCornerl = ' ', bottomCornerl = ' ', bottomCornerr = ' ', hyphen = ' ';

unsigned short cardNumber1 = rand_range(2,14);
unsigned short cardNumber2 = rand_range(2,14);

suit1 = rand_range(3,6);
suit2 = rand_range(3,6);

verticalLine = 179;
horizontalDouble = 205;
doubleCornerr = 187;
doubleCornerl = 201;
doubleCornerlb = 200;
doubleCornerrb = 188;
topLine = 196;
verticalDouble = 186;
topCornerr = 191;
topCornerl = 218;
bottomCornerl = 192;
bottomCornerr = 217;

//The next portion of code will ensure that the suits are different
if (suit1 == suit2)
    suit1 += 1;
if (suit1 == 6)
    suit1 = 3;
//The next portion will change the numbers 11,12,13,14 
// J, K, Q, A, respectively. 
string royalcard;

switch (cardNumber1 & cardNumber2) {
case 11:
royalcard = "J";
break;

case 12:
royalcard = "Q";
break;

case 13: 
royalcard = "K";
break;

case 14:
royalcard = "A";
break;

default:

break;
}
```

Comment: The value of the card and what you display to the user do not have to be the same type.  Think about an array of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Use an if or select...case to find out. Hope this is what you were looking for.

```
// x holds the random number you have generated
string royalcard;

switch (x) {
case 11:
royalcard = "Jack";
break;

case 12:
royalcard = "Queen";
break;

case 13: 
royalcard = "King"
break;

case 14:
royalcard = "Ace"
break;

default:

break;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it still just shows the numbers. The code that I have is really long but I will post a portion of it. @Jason

Comment: @user3479664 I'm not quite understanding what your problem is. Can you explain further? The switch...case won't change the value of cardNumber1 or cardNumber2. When it comes time to display the card on the screen, if the card number is 11 or greater, then display the value of royalcard instead of cardNumber1 or cardNumber2.

Comment: the homework is based on using the if statement. When I asked my teacher how to change 11, 12, 13, and 14, she told me that I would have to change the unsigned short for cardNumber to a string. That won't work because I am using the unsigned short to randomly generate those numbers. I am not sure how to get around this to replace the numbers with a character

Comment: I believe the way I suggested will work. You could also just from the beginning change rand_range() to return a string, which contains the result of rand() casted to it. And then change cardNumber to a string. Then if the string's value is >= 11 (you'll have to cast in your if statements), then replace it with the letter.

Comment: I have trouble with rand() to begin with so I'm not sure I know exactly what you mean. I am pretty new to C++.

Comment: rand_range()'s return value would become: return (string)rand() % (max - min + 1) + min; if I'm correct. Unless your teacher wants it done in a specific way, then I believe the way in my first comment would be the simplest to implement.

Comment: It won't let me do that. If I use string the way that you suggested it generates an error. Error 1 error C2275: 'std::string' : illegal use of this type as an expression c:\temp\hw8.cpp 25 1 hwProject